# How to get sorted members in this class?

Tags: python

I have the following class:

```
class ExampleValue:
    NULL        = 'null'
    BOOLEAN     = 'true'
    INTEGER     = '4'
    FLOAT       = '?'
    DECIMAL     = '?'
    STRING      = '"HELLO"'
    BYTES       = 'b"xyz"'
    DATE        = 'DATE "2014-01-01"'
    TIME        = 'TIME "01:02:03"'
    DATETIME    = 'DATETIME "2014-01-01T01:02:03"'
    INTERVAL    = 'INTERVAL 4 HOUR'
    GEOGRAPHY   = 'POINT(1 1)'
    JSON        = 'JSON "[1,2,3]"'
    STRUCT      = '{"x": 2}'
    ARRAY       = '[1,2,3]'
```

And I would like to iterate from the first one to the last. Is there a way to do this while keeping the ordering (or should I use a different 'type' than a class?). How I am currently doing it is:

```
>>> for val in ExampleValue.__dict__: # or dir(ExampleValue)
...     if not val.startswith('_'):
...         print (val)
...
INTERVAL
STRING
DECIMAL
FLOAT
BYTES
DATETIME
STRUCT
JSON
BOOLEAN
TIME
DATE
INTEGER
ARRAY
NULL
GEOGRAPHY
```

Comment: I can't replicate this. Curious what version of Python you are using.

Comment: @mark -- Python 3.9.2

Comment: I believe that [slots](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingSlots) will preserve ordering.

Comment: I'm curious about the version given [PEP 520](https://peps.python.org/pep-0520/) which seems to suggest this should already remain ordered (which is what I see when I run the code).

Comment: @Mark yes, actually you are correct. Perhaps I loaded the wrong shell when asking my question. As you suggest the `MappingProxy` preserves order, and doing `[v for v in ExampleValue.__dict__ if not v.startswith('_')]` works as-is.

Comment: same but with `vars` instead of dunder method: `for k, v in vars(ExampleValue).items():`

Comment: @cards -- sure, what's the difference though?

Comment: edited the comment. None... or maybe you freeze the state of the class into a dictionary

Comment: @Mark I added a note about what you said in my answer, is how I phrased it accurate?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this almost as-is, by just subclassing the `enum` class. For example:

```
from enum import Enum

class ExampleValue(Enum):
    NULL        = 'null'
    BOOLEAN     = 'true'
    INTEGER     = '4'
    FLOAT       = '?'
    DECIMAL     = '?'
    STRING      = '"HELLO"'
    BYTES       = 'b"xyz"'
    DATE        = 'DATE "2014-01-01"'
    TIME        = 'TIME "01:02:03"'
    DATETIME    = 'DATETIME "2014-01-01T01:02:03"'
    INTERVAL    = 'INTERVAL 4 HOUR'
    GEOGRAPHY   = 'POINT(1 1)'
    JSON        = 'JSON "[1,2,3]"'
    STRUCT      = '{"x": 2}'
    ARRAY       = '[1,2,3]'
```

```
for val in ExampleValue:
    print (val.name, val.value)
NULL null
BOOLEAN true
INTEGER 4
FLOAT ?
STRING "HELLO"
BYTES b"xyz"
DATE DATE "2014-01-01"
TIME TIME "01:02:03"
DATETIME DATETIME "2014-01-01T01:02:03"
INTERVAL INTERVAL 4 HOUR
GEOGRAPHY POINT (1 1)
JSON JSON "[1,2,3]"
STRUCT {"x": 2}
ARRAY [1,2,3]
```

The above works on `python2.7`. As @Mark mentioned above according to [Pep 520](https://peps.python.org/pep-0520/), the code in the question will work the same as the above on `python3.6` and above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
class Example(object):
    bool143 = True
    bool2 = True
    blah = False
    foo = True
    foobar2000 = False

example = Example()
members = [attr for attr in dir(example) if not callable(getattr(example, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]
print members
```